# How can I find out if anyone is currently on my website?

Tags: iis, iis-7

If I wanted to see if there are any users currently on my web site, how would I go about doing this?  (Excluding netstat) The server is Win Server 2008/IIS 7

Thanks
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS Performance Counters and IIS Logs are really the best guage for this, but a simple trick is to write an HTTPModule that keeps a hashtable of recent activity. This can simply keep a list of user ids (if they are authenticated), last accessed time, page requested, etc... This could be visuaized with a simple AXD path.